# What is the memory footprint for .NET Framework Compact Edition?

Tags: compact-framework, memory-footprint

What is the memory footprint for .NET Framework Compact Edition?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Micro_Framework), it's about 12MB

But then again, [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s6x0c3a4.aspx) says it'll run in 128KB to 1MB.

My guess is that it's going to vary based on how much memory you have available and it'll swap pieces in and out of memory depending on circumstances.  Quoting from the second link:

*Random access memory (RAM) is used to store dynamic data structures and JIT-compiled code. The .NET Compact Framework uses available RAM, up to a limit specified by the device, to cache generated code and data structures and then frees the memory when appropriate.*

*The common language runtime uses a code-pitching technique to free blocks of JIT-compiled code at run time when memory is low. This enables larger programs to run on RAM-constrained systems with minimal performance penalty.*

Answer (score 0):

Although [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Micro_Framework) is not about the compact framework (it's about the micro version), it shows a comparison between the Micro and Compact frameworks, noting that the .NET Compact Framework has a memory footprint of **12 MB**.